# Getting two characters from string in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, character

how to get in python from string not one character, but two?

I have:

```
long_str = 'abcd'
for c in long_str:
   print c
```

and it gives me like

```
a
b
c
d
```

but i need to get

```
ab
cd
```

I'm new in python.. is there any way?

Comment: related "What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i, j in zip(long_str[::2], long_str[1::2]):
  print (i+j)
```

or

```
import operator
for s in map(operator.add, long_str[::2], long_str[1::2]):
   print (s)
```

---

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) also provide a generalized implementation of this:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use slice notation.  `long_str[x:y]` will give you characters in the range `[x, y)` (where x is included and y is not).

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(long_str) - 1, 2):
...   print long_str[i:i+2]
... 
ab
cd
```

Here I am using the three-argument range operator to denote start, end, and step (see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

Note that for a string of odd length, this will not take the last character.  If you want the last character by itself, change the second argument of `range` to `len(long_str)`.